# keras: Use one model output as another model input

Tags: model, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, keras-2

I am adding a dense layer before InceptionResNetV2 model(pre-trained)
This is InceptionResNetV2 output

```
model_base = InceptionResNetV2(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
x = model_base.get_layer('avg_pool').output
x = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
```

This is the layer will be added

```
input1 = Input(shape=input_shape1)
pre1 = Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='SAME', 
input_shape=input_shape1, name='first_dense')(input1)
pre = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=pre1)
```

This is combining two models

```
 after = Model(inputs=pre.output, outputs=x)

 model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=after.output)

 model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

use

```
pre.output
```

as

```
after.input
```

But it doesn't works . How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First let's create a new model from model_base, because you want to get an earlier output.

Your code:

```
model_base = InceptionResNetV2(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
x = model_base.get_layer('avg_pool').output
x = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
```

New `model_base`:

```
model_base = Model(model_base.input, x)
```

Now, it's important to pass the output `pre1` to this model:

```
base_out = model_base(pre1)
```

That's it:

```
model = Model(input1, base_out)
```

Comment: I have another question. If I want to use my own layer 'pre1' replacing the model_base first layer, how can I solve it ?Thank you !

Comment: The first part of my answer becomes `short_base = Model(base_model.get_layer('theFirstYouWantToKeep').input, base_model.get_layer('avg_pool'))` --- The rest is the same.

Comment: I tried, but i get the error:TypeError: Input layers to a `Model` must be `InputLayer` objects. Received inputs: Tensor("conv2d_1/convolution:0", shape=(?, ?, ?, 32), dtype=float32).

Comment: I think you'll have to call layer by layer then....something like `out = base_model.layers[2](pre1)`. Then a loop from layers 3 to end: `out = model.layers[i](out)`. Then make a model from your first input to this `out`.

Comment: I think is may not bacause i use resnet, it has short cut, so the layer is not stacked one by one, if so, i get the dimension error. Is there another methods?

Comment: You can try to copy the resnet code and change it...: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/inception_resnet_v2.py

Comment: @DanielMöller In case the output layer of network A is merged layer. How can we pass first ncolumns of the merged layer as input to network B?

Comment: @DanielMöller Sorry to bring up an old thread question, but I have a question about this line:

`base_out = model_base(pre1)`

Here we are treating model_base as a regular model, and just getting the output `base_out`? We don't need to use `.output` in this case, if we want to feed the output to other models? Thanks.

Comment: @Moondra, we are "calling" `model_base` when we use `(pre1)` in front of it. This means we are getting an "output" `base_out` given an "input" `pre1`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it seems we can use models as layers.

Comment: Quick question, if I wanted to add the new trainable layer after (instead of before like in this post) what would be some key points to keep track of?  (I'm trying but its bugging up)

Comment: `inputs = Input(...)`, `outputs = YourLayer(...)(inputs)`, `outputs = model_base(outputs)`, `outputs = MoreLayers(...)(outputs)`, `model = Model(inputs, outputs)`.